# Uber API /v1/estimates/time responds No authentication provided

Tags: uber-api

In order to test if the urls I made is correct, I put them in my browser to see if I can GET results.

**First**, I tried `GET /v1/products` which should return all types of cars and I put it in the browser like this:

```
https://api.uber.com/v1/products?server_token=MY_TOKEN&latitude=39.914286&longitude=116.461745
```

Which works fine and gives me a big JSON of products:

```
{"products":[{"capacity":4,"product_id":"0ed2dbad-c769-41f5-b66d-0767da627f9e","price_details":{"service_fees":[],"cost_per_minute":0.25,"distance_unit":"km","minimum":10.0,"cost_per_distance":1.5,"base":0.001,"cancellation_fee":8.0,"currency_code":"CNY"},"image":"http:\/\/static.uberx.net.cn\/car-types\/mono\/mono-peoplesuber2.png","short_description":"People's Uber +","display_name":"People\u2019s Uber +","description":"People's Uber +"},{"capacity":4,"product_id":"6bf8dc3b-c8b0-4f37-9b61-579e64016f7a","price_details":{"service_fees":[],"cost_per_minute":0.25,"distance_unit":"km","minimum":10.0,"cost_per_distance":1.5,"base":0.001,"cancellation_fee":8.0,"currency_code":"CNY"},"image":"http:\/\/static.uberx.net.cn\/car-types\/mono\/mono-peoplesuber2.png","short_description":"People's Uber","display_name":"People's Uber","description":"People's Uber"},{"capacity":4,"product_id":"93a40036-2670-4a41-bc59-1e901ca33632","price_details":{"service_fees":[],"cost_per_minute":0.4,"distance_unit":"km","minimum":20.0,"cost_per_distance":2.3,"base":15.0,"cancellation_fee":15.0,"currency_code":"CNY"},"image":"http:\/\/static.uberx.net.cn\/car-types\/mono\/mono-china-uberx.png","short_description":"uberX","display_name":"uberX","description":"The low-cost Uber"},{"capacity":4,"product_id":"259df3b5-e062-4b2b-ab81-3e3fbba4b423","price_details":{"service_fees":[],"cost_per_minute":0.7,"distance_unit":"km","minimum":30.0,"cost_per_distance":3.85,"base":18.0,"cancellation_fee":20.0,"currency_code":"CNY"},"image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-black.png","short_description":"UberBLACK","display_name":"UberBLACK","description":"The original Uber"},{"capacity":4,"product_id":"d1b0005e-8e33-44f1-b1e5-b3f98138642a","price_details":{"service_fees":[],"cost_per_minute":0.25,"distance_unit":"km","minimum":10.0,"cost_per_distance":1.5,"base":0.001,"cancellation_fee":8.0,"currency_code":"CNY"},"image":"http:\/\/d1a3f4spazzrp4.cloudfront.net\/car-types\/mono\/mono-electric.png","short_description":"Electric Vehicles","display_name":"a","description":"a"}]}
```

**Then**, I tried `GET /v1/estimates/time`, with the **SAME COORDINATES** and **SAME SERVER TOEKN**, I made the url like this:

```
https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time?server_token=MY_TOKEN&start_latitude=39.914286&start_longitude=116.461745
```

But it returns:

```
{"message":"No authentication provided.","code":"unauthorized"}
```

If the token has expired it should not work with the `Products` API which actually is working fine, so I don't think that's the issue. Please help, thanks.

BTW, I am testing Uber API in China in case the location may affect the results here.

Comment: It id CDN issues. Check out your https://developer.uber.com API setting. Because for me it is working fine. [uberestimate.org](http://uberestimate.org) this my site and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GET /v1/estimates/time` endpoint has a regional dependency which is probably why it's not working for the China location. Try it out after creating your app on the China Developer dashboard: https://developer.uber.com.cn/ and using that server token with `api.uber.com.cn`.

Documentation for this can be found here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/china

Comment: Thanks, I just did what you said and server returned the complete info.