# Uber API /v1/estimates/price responds No authentication provided

Tags: uber-api

In my programe, I need to use the Uber api:

> /v1/estimates/price

,so I test it in chrome by postman, but it responses  No authentication provided.

I search the stackoverflow and find this page "[Uber API /v1/estimates/time responds No authentication provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563037/uber-api-v1-estimates-time-responds-no-authentication-provided?answertab=active#tab-top)".

According to the last answer from faarwa which guide the asker get the complete info, I think I would get the complete info like the asker, but in fact，I failed，I got the same response.

This is my url:

> https://api.uber.com.cn/v1/estimates/price?server_token=MyTooken&start_latitude=31.993750705445024&start_longitude=118.71421140272062&end_latitude=32.046405144489704&end_longitude=118.80070636431914

the response is:

> {
>       "message": "No authentication provided.",
>       "code": "unauthorized" }

BTW: I tested the api in China.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your curl command and it looks great. In fact, I get a response for the exact command with my server_token:

```
curl "https://api.uber.com.cn/v1/estimates/price?server_token=<SERVER_TOKEN>&start_latitude=31.993750705445024&start_longitude=118.71421140272062&end_latitude=32.046405144489704&end_longitude=118.80070636431914" | jq
```

My response is:

```
{
  "prices": [
    {
      "localized_display_name": "People's Uber +",
      "distance": 7.72,
      "display_name": "People's Uber +",
      "product_id": "...",
      "high_estimate": 34,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "minimum": 7,
      "low_estimate": 24,
      "duration": 2160,
      "estimate": "CN¥24-34",
      "currency_code": "CNY"
    },
    {
      "localized_display_name": "Uber Sedan",
      "distance": 7.72,
      "display_name": "Uber Sedan",
      "product_id": "...",
      "high_estimate": 111,
      "surge_multiplier": 1,
      "minimum": 20,
      "low_estimate": 86,
      "duration": 2160,
      "estimate": "CN¥86-111",
      "currency_code": "CNY"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's my assumption why your query doesn't work: You are trying to use Uber in China (based on the URL and location), which requires you to use an Uber app for China as well. Could you please validate if your app shows up in the [Uber Dashboard China](https://developer.uber.com.cn/dashboard/)? For more information, please check out the [China Guide](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/china) in our developer docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear - the reason it is not working is the app you created was not created in the Uber China Developer Dashboard. If you use credentials from a newly created app it should work as expected.